# Difference between Galois and other automorphisms

Tags: finite-fields

With respect to the definition of Galois field, for $E$ an extension of $F$ ($E$ and $F$ are finite fields) $\mathrm{Gal}\,(E/F)$ is the set of automorphisms of $E$ which fix $F$ pointwise. So I think that we can distinguish between $\mathrm{Gal}\,(E/F)$ and $\mathrm{Aut}\,(E)$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assume that $E$ and $F$ are finite fields. Every automorphism of a field fixes its prime field, by which I mean $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb F_p$, the field generated by $1\in E$. However it doesn't need to fix any other subfield, so that's what makes the Galois group different.

Comment: threfore the order of Aut(E) > Gal(E/F) ? E is considered as a vector space over F.

Comment: Certainly $\geq$, since every element of the Galois group is an automorphism of $E$.

Comment: Okay, then what about the difference between $Gal(E/F)$ and $Aut(E/F)$?  ...seems to sometimes depend on the author; you need to say something about normality.